# Get Row Count for Data Transferred using EzAPI SSIS

Tags: ssis, ezapi

I am transferring some data from one table to another using SSIS with EzAPI.  How can I get the number of rows that were transferred?

My setup is as follows

```
        EzPackage package = new EzPackage();

        EzOleDbConnectionManager srcConn;
        EzOleDbSource src;

        EzOleDbConnectionManager destConn;
        EzOleDbDestination dest;

        EzDataFlow dataFlow;

        destConn = new EzOleDbConnectionManager(package); //set connection string
        srcConn = new EzOleDbConnectionManager(package);

        dataFlow = new EzDataFlow(package);

        src = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EzOleDbSource), new object[] { dataFlow }) as EzOleDbSource;
        src.Connection = srcConn;
        src.SqlCommand = odbcImport.Query;

        dest = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EzOleDbDestination), new object[] { dataFlow }) as EzOleDbDestination;
        dest.Connection = destConn;
        dest.AttachTo(src, 0, 0);
        dest.AccessMode = AccessMode.AM_OPENROWSET_FASTLOAD;

        DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
```

Where in this can I add something to get the number of rows? For all versions of SQL server 2008r2 and up

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 or 2014?

Comment: I am using SQL 2008r2

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that the Row Count Transformation isn't included out of the box. I had a brief post about that: [Row Count with EzAPI](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/10/row-count-with-ssis-ezapi.html)

I downloaded the source project from CodePlex and then edited EzComponents.cs (in EzAPI\src) and added the following code

```
[CompID("{150E6007-7C6A-4CC3-8FF3-FC73783A972E}")]
public class EzRowCountTransform : EzComponent
{
    public EzRowCountTransform(EzDataFlow dataFlow) : base(dataFlow) { }
    public EzRowCountTransform(EzDataFlow parent, IDTSComponentMetaData100 meta) : base(parent, meta) { }

    public string VariableName
    {
        get { return (string)Meta.CustomPropertyCollection["VariableName"].Value; }
        set { Comp.SetComponentProperty("VariableName", value); }
    }
}
```

The component id above is only for 2008.

For 2012, it's going to be `E26997D8C-70DA-42B2-8208-A19CE3A9FE41` I don't have a 2012 installation at the moment to confirm I didn't transpose a value there but drop a Row Count component onto a data flow, right click and look at the properties. The component/class id is what that value needs to be. Similar story if you're dealing with 2005.

So, once you have the ability to use `EzRowCountTransform`, you can simply patch it into your existing script.

```
// Create an instance of our transform
EzRowCountTransform newRC = null;

// Create a variable to use it
Variable newRCVariable = null;
newRCVariable = package.Variables.Add("RowCountNew", false, "User", 0); 

// ...
src.SqlCommand = odbcImport.Query;

// New code here too
newRC = new EzRowCountTransform(dataFlow);
newRC.AttachTo(src);
newRC.Name = "RC New Rows";
newRC.VariableName = newRCVariable.QualifiedName;

// Continue old code
```

I have a presentation on various approaches I've used over time and what I like/don't like about them. [Type more, click less: a programmatic approach to building SSIS](http://sqlsaturday.com/viewsession.aspx?sat=191&sessionid=15953). It contains sample code for creating the EzRowCountTransform and usage.

Comment: If the code has to support all instances of SQL Server 2008r2 and up, can that still be done?

Comment: Sadly no. The [EzAPI](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21238) project has version specific releases specifically because those bloody IDs changed between builds. There are other ways to generate SSIS packages. My progression has been pure .NET api -> EzAPI -> Biml for package generation. I even have a presentation about it ;) [Type more, click less: programmatically build SSIS](http://sqlsaturday.com/viewsession.aspx?sat=191&sessionid=15953)

Comment: How would I use the EzRowCountTransform though?

Comment: Code updated to reflect usage. Again, approximate as I can't hit any could based storage. In the code in my linked presentation, there is a Driver.cs file that is very similar to your code.